# C++ default precision for scientific floating hex and decimal output

Tags: c++, precision

The test program below uses both printf and cout to display what I thought should be the same thing, and they are identical when run on a Mac using Xcode.  However, when run on Windows using VS2019 the precision of the hex floating point result is different.  I realize I can probably adjust the precision to make them match but is this actually a compiler problem or just a legal implementation dependent issue?

```
Output with VS2019:
    9.223377e+12 0x1.0c6f83e89c600p+43
    9.223377e+12 0x1.0c6f84p+43

Output with Xcode on a Mac:
    9.223377e+12 0x1.0c6f83e89c600p+43
    9.223377e+12 0x1.0c6f83e89c600p+43


#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   long double x = 9223377208547.0L;
   printf("%Le %La\n", x, x);
   cout << scientific << x << ' ' << hexfloat << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Note that on MSVC `long double` is the same as `double` - but I'm not sure if this is the issue, here. (Can you add a `sizeof(long double)` output to your code and run it on both Xcode/Mac and MSVC/Windows to let us know if there's a difference?)

Comment: Also note from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) that, "Hexadecimal floating-point formatting ignores the stream precision specification, as required by the specification of std::num_put::do_put."

Comment: Indeed double and long double are a different size on the Mac, but I changed the code to use just double instead and the results were the same.  The reference you give pertaining to the hex floating-point precision states in part: "...instead, the number is always printed with enough precision to exactly represent the value."  However, it seems that in the cout case MSVC is rounding the value to force a 6-digit precision.

Comment: Yeah - I saw that last point, eventually. The MSVC `cout` but prints the value to the accuracy of a **single precision** ('float') value. If you change 'x' to a `float` then the `printf` line shows: `0x1.0c6f840000000p+43`. Looks like a bug in MSVC (but clang-cl does the same, BTW).